# Taylor series for $\frac{1}{z-5}$ at $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I need to find Taylor series for $\frac{1}{z-5}$ at $z=i$

**My attempt:**

$$f(i)=\frac{1}{i-5}\\
f'(i)=-\frac{1}{(i-5)^2}\\
f''(i)=\frac{2}{(i-5)^3}\\
f'''(i)=-\frac{6}{(i-5)^4}\\
\Longrightarrow T(z)\approx \frac{(z-i)^0}{0!(i-5)}-\frac{(z-i)^1}{1!(i-5)^2}+\frac{2(z-i)^2}{2!(i-5)^3}-\frac{6(z-i)^3}{3!(i-5)^4}+\dots\\
$$ $$\Longrightarrow\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(z-i)^n}{(i-5)^{n+1}}$$

but the answer should be:

$$-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-i)^n}{(5-i)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: $-(5-i)^{n+1} = -(-1)^{n+1}(i-5)^{n+1} = (-1)^n(i-5)^{n+1}$.

Comment: @Kaster Great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $w = z - i$. Then 
$$\frac{1}{z-5}= \frac{1}{w - 5 + i}=\frac{1}{-5+i}\frac{1}{1 - \left(\frac{w}{5 - i}\right)} = -\frac{1}{5 - i} \sum_{n \geq 0} \left(\frac{w}{5 - i}\right)^n = -\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{w^n}{(5 - i)^{n+1}}, $$
valid for $|w| < |5 - i| = \sqrt{26}$.

Comment: ..Nice solution